# __getattribute__ function to return object value from another class

Tags: python, django, django-models, metaclass, getattr

I have a base class which has 2 attributes which itself are from another class. See the code below

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, obj1, obj2):
        self.obj1 = obj1
        self.obj2 = obj2

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if name == 'obj1':
            obj = object.__getattribute__(self, name) #self.obj1.value
            return object.__getattribute__(obj,'value')

class Temp(object):
    def __init__(self, value, type):
        self.value = value
        self.type = type

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        #if name == 'value':
        #    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        if name == 'type':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    temp_obj1 = Temp(45, type(45))
    temp_obj2 = Temp('string', type('string'))

    base_obj = Base(temp_obj1, temp_obj2)
    print base_obj.obj1
    print base_obj.obj1.type
```

and its output:-

```
45
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getattr.py", line 29, in <module>
    print base_obj.obj1.type
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'type'
```

Basically what I am trying to achieve is I don't have to call `base_obj.obj1.value` to get the `value` attribute of `obj1` but calling `base_obj.obj1` will give the desired result. But at the same time I am be able to call some function or property of `obj1` like `base_obj.obj1.type` or `base_obj.obj1.some_method()`

But as you can see I am getting the error. How can I achieve the desired functionality

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question right, you can't do what you're trying to do, and what's more, you really shouldn't.  Whatever `base_obj.obj1` is, `base_obj.obj1.type` will get the `type` attribute of that, because `base_obj.obj1.type` means `(base_obj.ob1).type` --- that is, it evaluates the `obj1` attribute first.  There is no way to make `base_obj.obj1` return one thing, but have the `base_obj.obj1` part of `base_obj.obj1.type` be something different.  At the time the lookup of `obj1` happens, you do not know whether another attribute lookup is going to take place later.

There are good reasons for this.  It would be very confusing if these gave different results:

```
# 1
x = base_obj.obj1.type

# 2
tmp = base_obj.obj1
x = tmp.type
```

If you want to get the `value` attribute, get the `value` attribute.  If you want to be able to *use* `obj1` in various situations as if it were its value attribute, you may be able to achieve what you want by overloading various operations on `obj1` (so that, e.g., `base_obj.obj1 + 2` works).